# How to put GUI Components in an OpenGL Screen

Tags: java, user-interface, opengl, jframe, jtextarea

I have an opengl program that I would like to put a text box / area in, but I am not sure if there is a way to do this in the opengl window I have. Is there any way to do this or embed it in OR maybe embed the opengl window into a JFrame?

Comment: At least you could give him a reason for the downvote...

Answer (score 4):

Of course there is a way - you can write your own GUI elements that render to OpenGL. As to whether or not you can embed this in a JFrame - this depends on the library you're using, in LWJGL you can probably do this with Display.setParent - it takes a awt.Canvas, I don't know if you can get one with Swing components.

I think it could be done like this:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class CanvasTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LWJGLException, InterruptedException {
        // note that this is a very bare bones
        // proof-of-concept thing. You'd want to 
        // install your own close handlers etc here.
        Canvas openglSurface = new Canvas();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.add(openglSurface);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(new JTextField("Hello World!"));
        openglSurface.setSize(500, 500);
        Display.setParent(openglSurface);
        Display.create();
        GL11.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Display.update();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Display.destroy();
    }
}
```

I didn't actually try this because I never needed this myself, but it should probably work.

Note: I did try now. It does indeed work, but apparently needs some extra work to make it play along with LayoutManagers and such.

Comment: alright, sweet thanks for the answer, I am gonna go try this out now.

Comment: I tried it too, but I couldnt get it to work, would you mind posting some more code to show how? I got Parent.isDisplayable() must be true as an error... Any ideas?

Comment: Added full working example. Very crude, but working. Btw, that's the error you get when you try to create the Display before `frame.setVisible(true);`